# Does solar wind perturb Earth's magnetic field ? If so, what are the consequences?

Tags: geomagnetism, severe-weather

The Earth's magnetic field makes continuous battle with external disturbances to protect Earth from unwanted ramifications. Asteroids passing by, solar flares, and other ET disturbances may cause magnetic field anomaly which may affect atmospheric circulation and convection which may cause wind and water storms such as tsunamis, tornadoes etc. It can also affect air transport by disrupting the normal functioning of engines and/or creating drag-force that either drags aeroplanes and ships down or forward, in general, causing unintended motion. Are there studies about,

1. the effect of ET perturbations on Earth's magnetic field.
2. are there historical evidences for the effects of such disturbances on Earth's weather and climate (e.g., the relationship between earth's magnetic field, B ~ convection, atmospheric circulation)
3. how much drag force can be generated from a minute disturbance from solar wind?

Comment: Is [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geomagnetic_storm) unsatisfactory?

Comment: What  are you calling ET disturbances or perturbations?